# Why are Python requests slower than MooTools and jQuery?

Tags: python, jquery, python-requests, mootools

I'm trying to create an API for a chat service. Sending a request after another is required for the chat to work. I started implementing it with Python requests but it was very slow. I also tried using a single session for every request...

It never matched the performance of MooTools and jQuery when I created an API on the browser in JS. What could be the reason and is there a way to make Python requests work faster?

Comment: JS is client-side. Python is server side. Python is slower as you have to wait for the request to travel across the internet to your server and back again. It may also be slow if your server is being flooded with requests or is not powerful enough. For the chat system to work, you will need a central server between all your users. Also note that if you're building a chat system you should really be using a two-way platform such as Websockets

Comment: Show your code in a fiddle like this one http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/xxwmxh0z/